# Finding peaks & valleys in vector if they correspond to certain values in another vector

Tags: r, function

let's assume I have following pairs of vectors:

first pair:

```
sig1 <- c(322, 398, 401, 345, 368, 361, 476, 551, 742, 601, 354, 355, 321, 376, 388, 394, 325, 355, 375, 325)
mov1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
```

second pair:

```
sig2 <- c(341, 378, 309, 345, 386, 341, 366, 301, 342, 311, 374, 345, 332, 393, 378, 394, 345, 361, 305, 335)
mov2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
```

I am trying to write an R function which takes a similar pair of vectors and returns the positions in which peak (or valley)* from the first vector (sig) corresponds to 1 in the second (mov) vector (this situation is illustrated in first example pair). If there are no peaks or peaks do not correspond with value 1, the function shall return 0 (second pair, no peaks above the threshold).

I used a slightly modified findpeaks function to identify peaks and valleys, but I am unable to find corresponding ones in the second vec.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure, what you are asking for. Perhaps `sig1[which(mov1 == 1)]` or defined as function: `findpeak <- function(sig, mov) { sig[which(mov == 1)] }` and `findpeak(sig1, mov1)`?

Comment: @MartinGal thank you for your hint. I forgot about which() function. Sometimes I forget about basic things.